# How to make chapter references follow section numbering?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, chapterbib

I have added Reference section for each chapter.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, I want Références to be a section like this : `2.6 Références`

I'm simply adding the code below in the end of each chapter to have a bibliography for the chapter.

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
```

Comment: Try `subbibnumbered` instead of `subbibintoc`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

`subbibintoc` adds the entry to the table of contents, but uses a `\section*` for the bibliography's heading. If you want a numbered section, you have `subbibnumbered` which uses a `\section` for the bibliography and, being numbered, also goes to the table of contents. (For classes without `\chapter`, those would be `\subsection*` and `\subsection`, respectively).